# element.trigger() not working in IE

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I implemented jQuery autocomplete with AngularJS.

```
app.directive("autoComplete", function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element) {
                var location = ["OMAHA, NE", "OMAHA, TX", "DALLAS, TX", "DALLAS, NE"];

                element.autocomplete({
                    source: location,
                    autoFocus: true,
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 3,
                    select: function () {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            element.trigger("input");
                        }, 0);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Before, autocomplete value selected from dropdown could not be passed to `ngModel`([JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ealonwang/7y25ru40/)). Then I added `element.trigger("input");`, and everything works fine (in Chrome or Firefox).

However, the problem still exists in IE (I am using IE 11). When autocomplete value selected from dropdown using "Enter" or "Left Click" or "Tab", it cannot be passed to `ngModel`. So the reason is `element.trigger("input");`somehow not working in IE.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
select: function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        //Assign the selcted value to ngModel: scope.<ngModelValue> = <selectedValue>;
    }, 0);
}
```